# What is the difference of webparts and websites?

Tags: .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5, web-parts

i dont know the actual use of webparts , so. better to know difference with webpage ?

any answer is appreriate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web part is a special type of web control that is part of a framework that allows users to personalize their web page by choosing which web parts they want on their page, and depending on the web part, personalizing the web parts.  (think of a weather web part where a user can define which city (or cities) they want to view the weather for.

So the difference is pretty huge, but basically web parts live inside of web pages.

Comment: A web page is something that lives on its own.  You can call a web page directly and have it served by your web server.  A web part, (on a grander scale) is more like your basic ASP.NET TextBox or GridView.  It doesn't have legs it can stand up on its own with.  It must be part of a web page in order to be served by your web server and seen by the users of your application or web site.

Answer (score 2):

Webparts are widgets that a user can add to a Web Part page to construct a custom web page.

They're used heavily in Sharepoint to allow users to easily construct their own pages without writing any code.

Answer (score 2):

webparts make up a webpage in sharepoint land.

Comment: Perfect - when I read this question, I had no idea what a web part was, let alone compared to a web page. You answered this in a useful way for the questioner, and for curious readers.

Comment: Except for the fact that you can use WebParts outside of Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Web Parts Controls [explained in details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

MS uses a lot of made-up terms for their own technologies. I don't think MS has a specific definition of web page, but that'd typicaly be your ASPX page.

As for webparts, they are a specific kind of .net control and could be considered 'widgets' for lack of a better term.

A web page (ASPX) may have multiple webparts.

The term 'web part' is used a lot in the context of SharePoint.